# Func<> operator in plain english

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking at creating a dynamic linq query where the `Where` operator will be different depending on the user's choice and I'm not that familiar with the framework. It seems I need to use the `Func` operator and I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around this syntax.

What does it do?  What does it mean? Can someone help me understand how it's used?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not an operator, rather a type of [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

Comment: Your question is very poorly laid out. Provide a few examples and what you mean by syntax. Do you mean **lambda expression?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Func<>` is simply a predefined delegate pattern:

```
protected bool SomeMethod(int input)
{
    return true;
}
```

This is a fairly standard method. You can make a delegate that targets this signature like so:

```
public delegate bool MyMethodType(int input);
```

This delegate is only good for methods taking 1 integer, and returning a bool. Func<> seeks to simplify this by making it generic:

```
public delegate T Func<T>();
public delegate U Func<T, U>(T input);
```

That's effectively what a Func<> is, just a generic delegate. This way, you can say all of these things:

```
Func<int, bool> myMethod = SomeMethod;
MyMethodType myMethod = SomeMethod;
```

In terms of LINQ, you will likely use the shorthand expression syntax; the compiler will turn the expression into a delegate for you:

```
.Where(x => x.SomeProperty > 10);
```

This statement is equivalent to:

```
.Where(delegate(int someProperty) { return someProperty > 10) })
```

It's all compiler syntax sugar.

Answer (score 2):

`Func<T>` is just a type name. It is not a special syntax.

What you need to wrap your head around are [**lambda expressions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). For example, consider this:

```
myCollection.Where(item => item.Size == 10)
```

This means the following: take all items in the collection `myCollection`, check if each item’s `Size` property equals `10`, and consider only the items for which this is the case.

There are many more such operators that use lambda expressions. There is a pretty good [**introduction to LINQ queries**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remember that `Func<>` means "function". A function is basically a method which returns a result.

For example :

- `Func<bool>` means "a function
  returning a bool"
- `Func<string,bool>` means "a function
  taking a string as only input parameter
  and returning a bool"
- `Func<bool,string,int,string,bool>`
  means "a function taking 4 input
  parameters which are respectively of
  types bool,string,int and string...
  returning a bool"

And so on : the types listed between the `<>` are the input parameters types in the right order, except the last which is the return type of the function.

Now, as far as `Where` is concerned, it requires a `Func<TSource, Boolean>` as argument, right ? That means that any method taking a `TSource` input argument and returning a `Boolean` (aka `bool`) will be okay there (with `TSource` being the type of each element in the collection filtered by `Where`).

That means : `Where` will keep only each `TSource` for which the chosen method will return `true`.

Example :
Your want to filter a list of firstnames to keep only those beginning by "T".

```
string[] firstnames = new string[] { "Albert", "Terry", "Bob", Tom", "Joe" };
string[] firstnamesBeginningWithT = firstnames.Where(beginsWithT).ToArray();
```

with `beginsWithT` being a method of this kind :

```
bool beginsWithT(string firstname)
{
   return firstname.StartWith("T");
}
```

a shortcut way exists, which makes unnecessary to create this one-liner method `beginsWithT` which will probably be used only one time :

```
string[] firstnamesBeginningWithT = firstnames.Where(firstname => firstname.StartWith("T")).ToArray();
```

which means "for each element in the collection, let's call it `firstname` by convenience and let's see if it starts with T". This syntax calls a "lambda expression" and is equivalent to a "method-on-the-fly-without-name", but like `beginsWithT` you will notice that it takes a `string` as input and returns a `Boolean`. It is therefore a kind of `Func<string,bool>` and fits `Where`'s needs.

Hope all is clearer for you now ! :-)
Ssithra

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`Func` is not an operator - it's just a generic delegate type. If you look at the signatures of the different "overloads" of it should become clearer:

```
Func<TResult>
Func<T, TResult>
Func<T1, T2, TResult>
```

The first one is a function that takes no arguments and returns a value, the second one is a function that takes one argument and returns a value, and so on.

All in all, it's essentially a helper type that enables you to define functions without separately defining a delegate type each time.

Now, none of this *really* helps much with dynamic Linq queries, but it is what you asked...

Answer (score 0):

`Func<T>` is just a type name. It is not a special syntax.

What you need to wrap your head around are [**expression trees**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). For example, consider this:

```
myCollection.Where(item => item.Size == 10)
```

If `myCollection` is of the type `IQueryable<T>`, then the compiler will turn this into an *expression tree* that represents the lambda expression `item => item.Size == 10`. If you are using this to access, for example, an SQL database, then this expression is automatically translated to SQL.

You can [**Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) as described on MSDN. In particular, you will be using many of the [static methods in the `Expression` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) to construct such an expression tree dynamically.